# Inviting users to Facebook game and leveling up the user who did the invite

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently adding an invite/recruit system to my Pirates canvas app iframe game. I have the invites working, but the user who sent the invite doesn't get credit for sending the invite. Is it possible to send url parameters in the invite so I can know that the user got invited by another user and to increment the other user's level? I have to add an i parameter to my server's page greenrobot.com/pirates/fb/?i=1807687 for the recruit system to work.

Here's my code:

```
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];

$app_id = "2342084241";

    //?i=$user
 $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/pirates/";

 $message = "You have been invited to play Pirates!";

 $requests_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id="
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
        . "&message=" . $message;

 if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
    echo "Request Ids: ";
    print_r($_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
 }
```

Comment: The request ids passed to your script allow you to read the actual request object data from the API – and that includes the sending user.

Comment: I tried that method to get the user id from the request id, but I got rate limited by Facebook before I could get it to work.  Thanks for the answer though.